# Set link of my navbar active with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I try to set active the element of my navbar when I click on the button.

My navbar is like that:

[image: navbar]

But when I click on the "a" for exemple, the "G" remains active.

My code is like that:

```
<div class="navbar span8" id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
             <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
             <li><a href="#b">B</a></li>
             <li><a href="#c">C</a></li>
             <li><a href="#d">D</a></li>
             <li><a href="#e">E</a></li>
             <li><a href="#f">F</a></li>    
              .....         
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

To set a class active the code is:

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#f">F</a></li>
```

How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: The below methods will be useful if you're only using the navbar on one page but if you're actually jumping between pages then you'll have to implement a solution using something else like cookies or possibly php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it active like this..

```
$('.nav li').click(function(){
    $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

<kbd>[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/62719)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

My solution works well when creating restful sites.

**The main JS is here:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var main_route = (window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]);
    $('#navbar_' + main_route).addClass('active');
});
```

**It works by:**

**1)** Finding the main route of the URL. For example if the url was "http://www.benyon.com/projects/first_project" it would get "projects".

***JS snippet***

```
var main_route = (window.location.pathname.split("/")[1]);
```

**2)** It then uses that to refer to the ID of the list element for that particular button using concatenation. For example:
`‘#navbar_’ + main_route` is the same as `‘#navbar_projects’`.

It then adds the “active” class using `addClass(‘active’)`.

***JS snippet***

```
$('#navbar_' + main_route).addClass('active');
```

***HTML snippet***

```
<li id="navbar_projects"><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
```

**The Downside**

For this to work your routes need to have the same name as the index of the element you want to highlight.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this code:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NM389/)

```
$('.nav li').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
})
```